# Multilevel Negative Binomial fails with MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I have a pretty complex multilevel neg. binomial regression that does not converge when using a regular MLE (but from what I understand, when dealing with multilevel models, MLE is not *regular*, per se).

The model nevertheless converges just fine when using Bayesian estimation, specifically Stan no u-turn sampling.

I am curious as to why that's the case? Is it some function of the data (extreme difficulty in finding the global maximum)?

Any explanation or literature suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you give us more details, this would be a guessing game.

Comment: Agree with Tim that more detail is warranted - without exact specification for both MLE (which package do you use?) and Stan (are you using Stan driectly or via rstanarm/brms?). Also it might be helpful to check if the `optimizing` method in Stan converges.

Comment: I was using `glmer` (`lme4`) and `brms` for estimation. None of the `glmer` optimization algorithms converged for the model.